# Search returns everything if search term has a space

Tags: search

When I try to search for terms with spaces, such as "lord of the rings", it returns all of my posts. However, if I just type "lord", it returns results.

Any ideas what would be causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chances are it's searching using the 'OR' operand, which for will pull up everything that has those common words - 'of the'.  There are a number of alternate search plugins for Wordpress - we've had great results (pun intended) using [Relevanssi](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/relevanssi/).

Comment: Relevanssi is really good. +1 You can set stop words in its settings too.

Comment: Does Relevanssi affect admin search as well?

Comment: It does, but I'm not sure how much it does there to be honest.  I know it affects the 'posts and pages' searching, but beyond that I can't really tell you a whole lot.  Mikko - the dev - is extremely helpful, but isn't so good at documentation (his words, not mine).